# "Add another" for many fields together, but collapsible

Tags: webforms

I need to collect information about multiple people - an unlimited number. So this means I need an "Add another" capability. [Think Field Collection or Paragraphs.] The only element I see that has the ability is the "Custom Composite." That works for collecting the data, but I really don't want to see a page worth of data on the first nine people as I am entering the tenth. Is there any way to make this custom composite also collapsible like "Details" is?

Comment: This is in a Webform

Comment: Well, it's not perfect, but I managed to kludge a "Details" section into a "Custom Composite". Lots of CSS work needed now.